# Trading platforms: 15 years old

Tags: trading, day-trading

I'm aged 15 and have been demo-trading for about a year now. I signed up with plus500 as they give quite good bonuses on deposits. I had to create an account with a fake D.O.B. I have just found out that to withdraw, it requires my passport info. Would this not allow me to withdraw? What about if I'm 18. Like, when I turn 18… will I be able to withdraw, even though the account and passport do not match. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you may have committed an act of fraud. You will want to be very careful, here, and at the very least, will want to talk to your parents about this.

Comment: I have resolved it. I am sharing an account with my parents now. Ty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend talking to your parents.  You may be able to convert the account to a joint account that is shared with them, and then they would be able to withdraw the money for you.